# Strange behaviour of tellg() function c++

Tags: c++

I got a problem with tellg() function from std::fstream class. Typically it should return the position of the current character in the input stream. However, it works very strange for me. Below is some short sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
char c;
ifstream czytaj;
czytaj.open("test_file.txt");

cout << czytaj.tellg() << endl;     //is 0 should be 0
czytaj.peek();                      //is 0 should be 0
cout << czytaj.tellg() << endl;     //is 2 should be 0    !!
czytaj.get(c);                      //is 3 should be 3
czytaj.get(c);                      //is 4 should be 4
cout << czytaj.tellg() << endl;     //is 6 should be 4    !!

int r; cin >> r;
return 0;
}
```

While the txt file looks like follows:

```
abcdefghij
kturjbkfvd
```

After compilation I get output like:

```
0
2
6
```

First use of tellg() works properly, it returns position 0 as its the beginning of the file. Unfortunatelly, each next use works like it adds +2 to the position. As the result I get letters 'c' and 'd' extracted from the stream. Both tellg() and peek() are supposed not to change the position, so I should get letters 'a' and 'b', while the correct result should be:

```
0
0
2
```

Such things happen if I use encoding ANSI in txt file. When I change it for Unicode, it works as it should. Also if I use ANSI and additionally binary mode ios::binary, it works properly as well. Strange fact is, on my other computer it works fine even with ANSI and without ios::binary. Why does it happen?

EDIT: Forgot to mention about very important fact. If I remove from this sample code all lines containing `tellg()`, the extracting is correct - I get letters 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: Works for me with g++4.7.2 libstdc++4.7.2.  What compiler/library are you using?

Comment: Its probably a UTF-X encoded file with a BOM marker on the front. dump the file using a hex editor and show us the content. On Linux Try: `od -t x1 -t c test_file.txt`

Comment: Does your input file contain any other symbols than `abcdefgh`? Maybe newlines or something else? Could it be that the file is in Unicode (UTF-16)?

Comment: @Inspired - Yes, it contains also newline symbol, just tested it now without newline and it works fine even in ANSI and no binary mode. Edited my problem and now the question is, why the newline symbols corrupt function tellg()? First newline is in position 11 and it starts working wrong even at posion 2

Comment: Text streams do not have a meaningful current position.  It is affected by the CRT have to look ahead to properly handle text encoding and character substitution.  The further away you get from Unix and ASCII, the more it will be off.

Answer (score 2):

`tellg()` tells you where the next "get" position in the file is. Since files in for example Windows that use CR+LF (`'\r','\n'`) as newlines have two characters as a newline, where the C++ (and C) standard requires that a newline is  LF `'\n'` as a single character, when your program reads a CR+LF sequence, the C runtime counts that as one character, but the file position where you get the next character from is two steps forward.

Comment: U r right, but what I dont understand is, why 2nd use of tellg() suddenly returns 2 instead of 0, while the stream wasnt moved at all, just peeked meanwhile. None character was extracted between these 2 uses of tellg().

Comment: Not sure. I'd say that's probably a bug.

Comment: Its more complex, mate. Cuz every combination like peek() + tellg() "increases" the position of 2, which is really ridiculous.

Comment: I still think that is not how it is intended to work - that is, it's a bug.

Comment: @MatsPetersson 2022 year. Bug is still present. VC compiler

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue. try to read the filestream binary:

```
    czytaj.open("test_file.txt",ios::binary);
```

it helped for me